# octave 3d plot with mesh out of experimental data

Tags: plot, 3d, octave, mesh

I have following problem.
I have a table with experimental data read in a Matrix A(a,b,c) like this:

```
4.00000   7.00000   0.09035
4.00000   6.00000   0.02632
4.00000   5.00000   0.01184
4.00000   4.00000   0.30728
4.00000   3.00000   0.16022
4.00000   2.00000   0.01734
3.00000   6.00000   0.05817
3.00000   5.00000   0.02296
3.00000   4.00000   0.00000
3.00000   3.00000   0.22576
3.00000   2.00000   0.08331
3.00000   1.50000   0.00297
2.00000   6.00000   0.00000
2.00000   5.00000   0.05184
2.00000   4.00000   0.01883
2.00000   3.00000   0.00000
2.00000   2.00000   0.10719
2.00000   1.50000   0.06689
```

My actual problem is, that i do not know how to do a 3d plot with mesh. Wioth plot3d() i just a a curve, which is useless for me.
Like a older question was answered, the solution should be like this:

```
X = reshape(A(:,1),m,n);
Y = reshape(A(:,2),m,n);    % might be reshape(data(:,2),n,m)
Z = reshape(A(:,3),m,n);
mesh(X,Y,Z);
```

with the explanation:
In this case the assumption is that you have m unique values in Y, and n unique values in X. You may have to transpose these in your call to mesh as mesh(X',Y',Z) or something like that.

As i understood the explanation m and n must be the amount of grid points in x and y direction of my 3d plot. The problem i have is, that for example the grid points in y direction corresponding to one grid point in x direction can change from point to point.

With

```
 aa=unique(a)
 bb=unique(b)
 lengthaa=length(aa)
 lengthbb=length(bb)
```

I get the final grid scale of my 3d plot (n,m)=((lengthaa),length(bb)),but when i want to reshape A like i wrote it above, i get of course an error message like this:

```
 octave:20> x = reshape (A(:,1),clength,dlength)
 error: reshape: can't reshape 36x1 array to 6x12 array
```

And now i am at a point where i even don't know what to search for. Can you please help? :)

Edit:
Now I'm a step further:
with

```
 [aaa,bbb]=meshgrid(aa,bb)
```

I have the right skaling of my axes. Now i have to order my data in a right way.

Edit2: The problem is, that i have now grid points for which i do not have any data. Thats the reason, why reshape does not work. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate the missing point you could possibly interpolate the data. I did a quick test as I had a similar problem:

```
# Test script for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19604387/octave-3d-plot-with-mesh-out-of-experimental-data
# Trygve Utstumo, 2013-10-28

data = [
4.00000   7.00000   0.09035
4.00000   6.00000   0.02632
4.00000   5.00000   0.01184
4.00000   4.00000   0.30728
4.00000   3.00000   0.16022
4.00000   2.00000   0.01734
3.00000   6.00000   0.05817
3.00000   5.00000   0.02296
3.00000   4.00000   0.00000
3.00000   3.00000   0.22576
3.00000   2.00000   0.08331
3.00000   1.50000   0.00297
2.00000   6.00000   0.00000
2.00000   5.00000   0.05184
2.00000   4.00000   0.01883
2.00000   3.00000   0.00000
2.00000   2.00000   0.10719
2.00000   1.50000   0.06689
];

# Evenly spaced axis, hacked to this dataset 
xi = min(data(:,1)):max(data(:,1));
yi = min(data(:,2)):0.5:max(data(:,2));

zi = griddata( data(:,1),data(:,2),data(:,3),xi,yi);

mesh( xi, yi, zi )
print("figure.png")
pause()
```

[image: Sample output, you may want to increase the interpolation resolution a bit]